# Updating a set of data from the output of a Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to write up a query that are merging duplicate client records in to a single record. Right now I am just building a mapping table to know what I should map with what.

Here are the two functions I wrote to aid me in this

```
CREATE FUNCTION FindDuplicateClients ()
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
(
    select distinct CLIENT_GUID 
    from CLIENTS c
    inner join
    (
        select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOME_PHONE
        from CLIENTS
        group by FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOME_PHONE
        having COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t on c.FIRST_NAME = t.FIRST_NAME and c.LAST_NAME = t.LAST_NAME and c.HOME_PHONE = t.HOME_PHONE)
go

--Find other clients that map to this client
CREATE FUNCTION FindDuplicateClientsByClient (@Client uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
(
    select distinct CLIENT_GUID 
    from CLIENTS c
    inner join
    (
        select x.FIRST_NAME, x.LAST_NAME, x.HOME_PHONE
        from CLIENTS x
        inner join 
        (
            select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOME_PHONE
            from CLIENTS
            where CLIENT_GUID = @Client
        ) y on x.FIRST_NAME = y.FIRST_NAME and x.LAST_NAME = y.LAST_NAME and x.HOME_PHONE = y.HOME_PHONE
        group by x.FIRST_NAME, x.LAST_NAME, x.HOME_PHONE
        having COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t on c.FIRST_NAME = t.FIRST_NAME and c.LAST_NAME = t.LAST_NAME and c.HOME_PHONE = t.HOME_PHONE
    where CLIENT_GUID <> @Client)
go
```

The first function successfully returns all `CLIENT_GUID`'s that have more than 1 record, the second you pass in a GUID and it returns all other guids that share the "Common Information" (first name, last name, and home phone in this case)

The problem is filling out my mapping table. I have some rules I need to follow to give priority to some of the duplicates. For example anyone who has had transactions needs to not have their `CLIENT_GUID` changed, but they are able to have other GUIDs merged in to them (if the other GUIDs had no transactions)

```
--Create Mapping table
select CLIENT_GUID, CAST(null as uniqueidentifier) as NEW_CLIENT_GUID
into #mapping
from FindDuplicateClients()

--Do not map people who have transactions
update #mapping
set NEW_CLIENT_GUID = CLIENT_GUID
where CLIENT_GUID in (select CLIENT_GUID from trnHistory)
```

Now here is where I am running in to trouble. I don't know how to get the list of people who had `NEW_CLIENT_GUID` set in the previous query, run `FindDuplicateClientsByClient` against that GUID, and set `NEW_CLIENT_GUID` of any result to the `NEW_CLIENT_GUID` that was fed in to the function without using a cursor.

Here is the method I came up with using a cursor

```
declare cur cursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD for select NEW_CLIENT_GUID from #mapping where NEW_CLIENT_GUID is not null
declare @NEW_CLIENT_GUID uniqueidentifier

open cur
fetch next from cur into @NEW_CLIENT_GUID
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    update #mapping
    set NEW_CLIENT_GUID = @NEW_CLIENT_GUID
    where CLIENT_GUID in (select CLIENT_GUID from FindDuplicateClientsByClient(@NEW_CLIENT_GUID)) --Find duplicates to this record
        and NEW_CLIENT_GUID is null --Do not reassign values that are already set (ie: duplicates that have transactions)

    fetch next from cur into @NEW_CLIENT_GUID
end 

close cur
deallocate cur
```

To me, iterating over each result in `#mapping` that has a value set does not seem correct to me. What would be the correct way to do this? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 but I would prefer if it was compatible with SQL Server 2005 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been two days and no answers, I just stuck with my cursor solution as it was performant enough for what I needed to do.

I did use a different method when I had to loop through a second time to find people who where not mapped in the previous pass, but it is just a while loop which behaves exactly like the previous cursor.

```
declare @tmpGuid uniqueidentifier
select @tmpGuid = CLIENT_GUID from #mapping where NEW_CLIENT_GUID is null 
while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
begin   
  --Set the first unset guid to itself
  update #mapping
  set NEW_CLIENT_GUID = @tmpGuid
  where CLIENT_GUID = @tmpGuid

  --set all other duplicates to the guid we just used.
  update #mapping
  set NEW_CLIENT_GUID = @tmpGuid
  where CLIENT_GUID in (select CLIENT_GUID from FindDuplicateClientsByClient(@tmpGuid))
       and NEW_CLIENT_GUID is null

  --get next guid
  select @tmpGuid = CLIENT_GUID from #mapping where NEW_CLIENT_GUID is null 
end
set nocount off
go
```